# UI for adding/removing groups of form fields

Tags: forms, dynamic-ui

I have this block/group of form fields, which together form a 'location' object.

**How should I show the add and delete buttons for these objects?**

I need one 'add location' button/icon, and a 'remove location' button/icon for each location (unless there is only one -- you can't delete the location if it's the only one). Note that a location consists of the 'Hours' fields as well as the general info and contact fields.

Here's what's in place so far:

[image: Here's what's in place so far]

Comment: Could we get a picture of how your design looks when there are several locations added already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my suggestion:

1. "add location" should be displayed below form (footer). It's more covinient - user completing the form, from top to bottom... and then can decide to add new location,
2. "remove location" should be displayed as header of each location - on the level of current "add location". additionaly remove button should be similar to "add ...". 
   in addition if You highlite header and footer of each location, add horizontal line between locations - it should be clear enought.

Answer (score 2):

There is some inconsistency in you mockup. The groupbox' title reads "Locations", yet you only show 1 location's details.

There should be an overview of all locations, where you can see all locations, which should have a button to add, delete and edit locations.

Both the add end edit buttons should show your mockup, but instead of "Locations" it should read "Location details", and there should be a save and cancel button of some sort at the bottom.